# Watermark Script without PHP server

Tags: javascript, watermark

Can we use image watermark on an uploaded image without using PHP but only JS instead?

I dont want to save the image. I just want to combine two images by using watermark method but not to save on server. When the page is reloaded, the image should be gone.

https://transloadit.com/demos/image-resize/watermarking

For example the watermark script on the top. I want to do just the same but when the page reloaded, i dont want the uploaded image anymore.

Can we do this? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose that's what canvas is meant for. Of course, you must be aware that it can only be used for aesthetic purposes since the raw original picture is available at the browser.

Comment: You could, but it wouldn't be remotely secure. In order to do the watermarking in JS, you need to serve up the unwatermarked image to the browser, in which case the user can just save that instead.

Comment: I suppose you *are* using PHP, so you can do the watermark on the server and send the output in the response (with the appropriate header for the image type). You don't have to save the image from the watermark step to do this.

Comment: Doing it with JS would just be like if you add an overlay div with a logo on top of your image with CSS (which would be faster and as much non-secure). I think @JaredFarrish 's option is what you need for a safe, on demand (nothing saved) watermarking system.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your effective answers. Apparently, I should be work php. I did not want to get any help to do this but i really need now :) thanks a lot